# Extremely slow rendering of colorized text using Label instances

Tags: codenameone

I was trying to partially colorize text by putting Label instances without margin and padding into a Container - testing it I realized how slow this rendered.

Now I am curious why this might happen.

I looked into the simulators performance monitor but don't understand what might cause this.

Here is the code:

```
public class FormReSplit extends Form {
    Runnable runnableFilter;

    public FormReSplit() {
        super("FormReSplit", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        setScrollableX(false);
        setScrollableY(false);
        String[] words = new RE(" ").split("Paddy Corcoran's wife was for several years afflicted with a disease that nobody could properly understand. Nobody could tell what the matter with her was. She lay a bedridden invalid, trying doctors and quacks of all sorts, sexes, and sizes, till Paddy at last had just one comfort: she wouldn't be long with him—long troubling him. The seventh year was on the point of closing, when, one harvest day, as she lay moaning over her hard condition. Then a little woman who was dressed in a neat red cloak, came in and sat down by the hearth, saying: \"Well, Kitty Corcoran, now you have been lying on your back for seven years, and just as far from being cured as ever. But you may be blamed for it.\" \"How is that?\" asked Kitty bewildered. \"You see, for the last seven years you have been annoying us, the good people, and since I have a regard for you, I have come to let you know why you have been sick so long. While you have been ill, your children has thrown your dirty water out of the door after dusk and before sunrise, just when we are passing your door, which we do twice a day. Now, if you avoid this, if you throw it out in a different place and at a different time, your disease will leave you, and you will be as well as ever before. If you don't follow this advice, why, remain as you are, and all the arts of man cannot cure you.\" She then bade her good-bye, and disappeared. Kitty, who was glad to be cured on such easy terms, at once complied with the injunction of the fairy; and next day she was in as good health as ever, enjoying life once again.");
        TextField textField = new TextField("e") {
            @Override
            public void setText(String aText) {
                boolean change = !getText().equals(aText);
                super.setText(aText);
                if (change) {
                    filter();
                }
            }
        };
        add(textField);
        Container container = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        container.setName("matchingWords");
        container.setScrollableX(false);
        container.setScrollableY(true);
        add(container);
        runnableFilter = () -> {
            String matchcode = textField.getText();
            container.removeAll();
            int tally = 0;
            for (String word: words) {
                String[] parts = (null != matchcode && !matchcode.trim().equals(""))
                        ? new RE(matchcode).split(word)
                        : new String[] {word};
                if (parts.length > 1 || (parts.length == 1 && parts[0].length() < word.length())) {
                    int index = 0;
                    LinkedList<String> tokens = new LinkedList<>();
                    LinkedList<Boolean> matches = new LinkedList<>();
                    for (String part: parts) {
                        if (part.equals("")) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        int indexOf = word.indexOf(part, index);
                        if (indexOf > index) {
                            String matched = word.substring(index, indexOf);
                            if (!matches.isEmpty() && matches.getLast()) {
                                tokens.add(tokens.removeLast() + matched);
                            } else {
                                tokens.add(matched);
                                matches.add(true);
                            }
                            index = indexOf + part.length();
                        } else {
                            index += part.length();
                        }
                        tokens.add(part);
                        matches.add(false);
                    }
                    if (index < word.length()) {
                        String matched = word.substring(index, word.length());
                        if (!matches.isEmpty() && matches.getLast()) {
                            tokens.add(tokens.removeLast() + matched);
                        } else {
                            tokens.add(matched);
                            matches.add(true);
                        }
                    }
                    Container containerFlow = new Container(new FlowLayout());
                    containerFlow.setName("match" + tally++);
                    while (!tokens.isEmpty()) {
                        String token = tokens.pop();
                        Label labelMatched = new Label(token);
                        Style styleMatched = labelMatched.getAllStyles();
                        styleMatched.setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
                        styleMatched.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                        if (matches.pop()) {
                            styleMatched.setBgColor(0xffc0c0);
                            styleMatched.setFgColor(0xff0000);
                        } else {
                            styleMatched.setBgColor(0xf0f0f0);
                            styleMatched.setFgColor(0xc0c0c0);
                        }
                        styleMatched.setBgTransparency(255);
                        containerFlow.add(labelMatched);
                    }
                    container.add(containerFlow);
                }
            }
            container.animateLayout(400);
            textField.startEditingAsync();
        };
        filter();
    }

    protected void filter() {
        if (null != runnableFilter) {
            Display.getInstance().callSerially(runnableFilter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might have been a strange condition on my machine. I tried to profile the simulator using JVisualVM which caused a lot of exceptions. Therafter it was fast again.

Comment: While this would have some overhead we used a similar pattern as explained here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-lightweight-rich-text-view.html I'm guessing this has more to do with the editing and less with the rendering. Probably due to repeated revalidate calls while editing